# Using Void Function in C/C++ Windows API

Tags: c++, c, windows, api, user-interface

I would just like to know how to implement a void function (which for instance returns a string) in a C/C++ GUI program and show the output in a window.

Would you put it in a WM_CREATE case in the WndProc function or under the WinMain function? Or is it more complicated, as in, you have to redirect the Command Prompt output to the window?

Edit:
So, I have, for example...

```
void function() {
    cout << "Hello";
}
```

and then I want to implement this in a GUI...

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
    g_szClassName,
    "The title of my window",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 240, 120,
    NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    // Implement function somewhere here?

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.... Maybe a code sample would help?

Comment: `void` _'which for instance **returns** a string'_ sounds a bit contradictionary for my understanding. Did you mean a _reference_ parameter?

Comment: You are not really explaining what your problem is. Are you interested in void functions, WM_CREATE, WndProc or what?

Comment: So, I have, for example...
`
    void function() {
        cout << "Hello";
    }
`
and then I want to implement this in a GUI...
    LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_CLOSE:
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                break;
            case WM_DESTROY:
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return 0;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to go as low level as WndProc

The most basic way to implement a multiple return function in general is to pass by reference, for example

```
void someFunction(string* aS)
{   //do something
    aS = someString;        
}
```

It should be impemented something like this

```
string someString;

someFunction(&someString);

ShowMessage(someString);
```